# How do perform logging or debug output in a server script?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'd like to output some data to the console or any other visible place to help with debugging. Apparently `Logger.log()` doesn't do that, or if it does, I have no idea where to see the results (at least in the preview mode).

Is there any functionality for debug output in the server scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly encourage you to check the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server#troubleshooting) to get to know the basics. Using `console.log("test")` will log anything to the server side logs, which you can access from the preview mode.

Comment: This piece of documentation slipped past me somehow. I assumed that since server scripts are essentially AppScript, `console` is irrelevant for them and `Logger` is. Bonus question: does `Logger` actually do anything there?